# Is v[i++] undefined in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to code a function that checks a through a `char* a[]`, and often end up using something like

```
if(a[i] == 'x'){
    i++;
    //...
}
```

Now I would really like to change this to `a[i++]` instead, but it doesn't seem to work.

Question:

Am I doing something wrong here, or is there a clean alternative to avoid the `i++`?

Note: Currently 3 of my 13 rows in the function are `i++`, which makes it look significantly larger than it really is.

Comment: can you add an example where it is not working?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's just an issue I had a few weeks back and have been unable to find any information on whether or not it's legal or non-legal C. When discussing it with my room mate he had had similar issues with it, so I decided to ask if it was legal. If I run across issues with it again today I'll return here ;)

Comment: It is not undefined, but has different semantics.

Comment: It is not undefined, but bad practise in general. I've already spotted a couple SO `C` questions in the past weeks where people were doing this, and it was the eventual cause of an unexpected segfault. Consider refactoring your code to use proper `for` loops. It might be an extra line or two of code, but will save you a ton of hassle and re-writes down the road. Best of luck!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`if (a[i++] == 'x')` by itself is fine in C. It is, however, semantically different: Your original code only increments `i` if the condition is true, whereas `if (a[i++] == 'x')` always increments `i`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to take that into account!

Answer (score 2):

`v[i++]` is not undefined if `v[i]` is not undefined and `i++` doesn't cause an overflow of signed integer.

```
if(a[i++] == 'x'){
    ...
}
```

if not equivalent to

```
if(a[i] == 'x'){
    i++;
    ...
}
```

because the former inclements `i` every time this is executed,
but the latter inclements `i` only if `a[i] == 'x'` is true.

`++i` is an alternative to avoid `i++`. Note that the value of `++i` differs from `i++`. `(++i)-1` may be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to take that into account!

Comment: How is `(++i)-1` any better than `i++`?

Comment: I don't think `(++i)-1` is better than `i++`. It is just an alternative for those who hates `i++`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Someone who hates `i++` and thus replaces it with `(++i)-1` is either clueless or has issues we can't fix here.