# is a[i++] = 3 undefined?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I'm a novice programmer (been learning C on a CS course since September) I've been reading the following two questions in order to try and get my head around sequence points and the undefined behaviours which relate to them.

[Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior)

[Why is a = i + i++ undefined and not unspecified behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572618/why-is-a-i-i-undefined-and-not-unspecified-behaviour)

I now understand that

```
a[i] = i++;
```

results in an undefined behaviour. I was wondering if

```
a[i++] = 4;
```

falls into the same category but I can't find anyone discussing this specific example anywhere.

Comment: [No. It isn't UB](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32798674/3049655)

Comment: No.. It is not undefined

Comment: It's also a fairly common idiom.

Comment: @CoolGuy I don't think this is a duplicate; if you read the question you suggested, the question body doesn't seem to relate to the title...

Comment: @BenWainwright Yes. But, I remember a similar question being asked and gained a lot of votes but now, can't seem to find it...

Comment: @CoolGuy ok, but for now could you remove that duplicate link as it is misleading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fine.

The problem with `a[i] = i++;` is that the modification in `i++` is separate from the read in `i` in `a[i]`. The modification could take place before, during or after that read.

Since `a[i++] = 4;` doesn't read `i` independently from its modification, you don't have that problem.

Answer (score 6):

No, the latter is not undefined behavior because you're not modifying and  accessing `i` more than once between two sequence points.